# Execution context does not move from getStaticPaths to getStaticProps as it normally does

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to fetch data from a dynamic route. I'm in pages/science-and-engineering/[field].js and I'm using getStaticPath with getStaticProps as usual but for some reason getStaticProps never get executed, and the component never renders. ONLY getStaticPath get executed and everything works fine in there, and then it just stops.

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
       const results = await fetch('randomapi');
       const fields = await results.json();
       const paths = fields.map(field => ( { params: { field: field.name } } ) );
       console.log(paths) // EVERYTHING IS FINE HERE
       return { paths, fallback: false }
   }

export const getStaticProps = async ({params}) => {

    // NOTHING IN HERE GETS CALLED

    console.log('context: ', context)
    console.log('yo')
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/fields/computer-science`)
    const field = await res.json()
    console.log('field: ', field)
    return { props: {field: field} }

  
}

const Details = ({ field }) => {
    // NOTHING IN HERE GETS CALLED
    // render component blabla
}
export default Details;
```

And it ends up with 404 page. I literally have zero clue of what's going on because I'm doing the exact same thing in other files without problems. Have found 0 people online with the same issue.

The question is basically, why doesn't the execution context move on from getStaticPaths to getStaticProps as it normally does?

Comment: In the terminal console nothing, the server just keeps running and none of the console logs in getStaticProps gets executed. In the web console I get this one: GET http://localhost:3000/science-and-engineering/computer-science 404 (Not Found). "computer-science" should be the dynamically created page

Comment: The mistake I did with the post was thinking that it was a good idea to make a "general" path, the path really is pages/science-and-engineering/[field].js, and I'm changing that in the post now

Comment: When you log `paths` to the console, is `computer-science` in there? Are all the expected paths being generated there?

Comment: Finally figured it out, field.name was set to 'Computer Science' and not 'computer-science'... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params returned in `paths` must match your dynamic route path: `pages/posts/[name]`. You need to replace `field` with `name`.

```js
const paths = fields.map(field => ( { params: { name: field.name } } ) );
```

Also, make sure that all the expected paths are correctly generated in your `paths` array, including `computer-science`.

Comment: Changed the post now, I already have [field] in the path and not [name] so that's not the issue. Sorry for the bad post

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect what was discussed in the comments.