# I have a error with getStaticPath function

Tags: next.js

I have an error  ( A required parameter (BlogPreview) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /Blogs/[BlogPreview] ) 4

this is my code below I try to solve it but I don't understand what the problem is :

```
import axios from "axios";
import Footer from "../../src/components/Footer"
 import Header from "../../src/components/Header";
/* import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'; */
 import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
 import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";


 export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

 const res = await axios.post(`http://52.54.161.160:30007/blog/`);
 const articles = await res.data.success

 const paths = articles.map( blog => {
   return {
     params: { id: blog._id.toString() },
   }
 })
 return {
   paths,
   fallback: false
 }
 }

 export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
   const id = context.params._id;
   const res = await axios.post(`http://52.54.161.160:30007/blog/` + id);
   const articles = await res.data.success;

   return {
     props: {blog: articles}
   }
 }




 const BlogPreview = ({blog}) => {



   return (
         <>
      <Header/>

    <div className="container-fluid py-5">
      <div className="col-6 BlogPreviewBox px-5 ">
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <img className="display-blog-box my-5" src={blog.urlToImage}></img>
        </div>

        <h1 className="blog-preview-heading">
          {blog.title}
        </h1>
        <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
          <span className="text-center py-3">07 December 2021</span>
          <button className="btn-blog-display">2 min read</button>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div className="row display-blog-content-row">

            <p>{blog.description}</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}
export default BlogPreview;
```

I don't understand what the problem is in this code I check again and again but could not understand the problem I hope some one helps me

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Execution context does not move from getStaticPaths to getStaticProps as it normally does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67355355/1870780)? The params returned in paths must match your dynamic route path: `/Blogs/[BlogPreview]`. Replace `id` with `BlogPreview`.

Comment: can you please show me example

Comment: Change the following line `params: { id: blog._id.toString() },` to `params: { BlogPreview: blog._id.toString() },`. Then in `getStaticProps` change `const id = context.params._id` to `const id = context.params.BlogPreview`.

Comment: thank you very much juliomalves my problem is solved